# Assembly Language Search Again

Tags: assembly

I am attempting to make a program that will input numbers into an array then be able to search the array for one of the numbers.I can get it to read and search alright to find the number but the user is supposed to be able to search again, where I have to compare their input to "n" and "N". I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I am not sure if using atow is the correct input or not, but here is the code.

```
number1         WORD        ?
anArray         WORD        100 DUP (?)
count           WORD        ?
search          WORD        ?
searchn         BYTE        "n",0
searchNo            BYTE        "N",0
prompt1         BYTE        "Enter a number or -1 to quit.", 0
prompt2         BYTE        "Enter a number to search for", 0
prompt3         BYTE        "Search for another number Y/N",0
inString        BYTE        40 DUP (?)
outMsgLabel     BYTE        "Search Result", 0
frontOut1       BYTE        6 DUP (?)
outMsg1         BYTE        " is element"
rearOut1        BYTE        6 DUP (?),0
frontOut2       BYTE        6 DUP (?)
outMsg2         BYTE        " is not in array",0

searchAgain:    input       prompt3, inString, 40
                atow        inString
                mov         dx,ax
                atow        searchn
                mov         ax,"n"
                cmp         ax,dx
                je          end1
                atow        searchNo
                mov         ax,"N"
                cmp         ax,dx
                je          end1
                jmp         next
```

I have only included the snippets of the code that doesn't work and my .DATA section.

Comment: Write it in a high-level language first, and then convert it.  And then use a debugger to debug it.

Comment: I have been using a debugger, but I am learning Assembly Language in my college course. I tried writing it in C++ and converting it over, but I can't find it. It seems to be with the converting inString to a word because it produces 0 in the ax register. My teacher never taught us how to compare strings or even convert strings.

Comment: What architecture is this? It looks a bit like i86 in masm, but I don't recognise `atow` or `input`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does everyone say write it in a HLL first?

Why are you using WORD sizes?  Use the natural size of the processor 32 bit.

What Assembler is this?  If it is MASM or any other, are input, atow macros or functions?  Well either way, you are trying to convert the address of inString to a word not its contents

Try this:

```
prompt3         BYTE    "Search for another number Y/N ? >"
PROMPT3_SIZE    equ     $ - prompt3



 SearchAgain:
    push    PROMPT3_SIZE
    push    offset prompt3
    call    WriteToConsole

    call    GetKeyCode
    cmp     eax, 78         ; N
    je      end1
    cmp     eax, 110        ; n
    je      end1
    cmp     eax, 65         ; Y
    je      Continue        
    cmp     eax, 97         ; y
    je      Continue

    ; invalid char was entered, do whatever here
    jmp     SearchAgain     

end1:
    ; don't want to search again
Continue:
    ; search for character

; ...
; ...
; ...
    push    0
    call    ExitProcess
WriteToConsole:
    enter   0, 0

    push    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call    GetStdHandle

    push    0
    push    0
    push    [ebp + 12]
    push    [ebp + 8]
    push    eax
    call    WriteConsole

    leave
    ret     4 *2

GetKeyCode:
    push    STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    call    GetStdHandle

    push    eax
    call    FlushConsoleInputBuffer

    call    crt__getch
    xor     ecx, ecx        ; zero ecx for non extended key return value
    test    eax, eax
    jz      @F
    cmp     eax, 0E0h
    jnz     quit
@@:
    call    crt__getch
    mov     ecx, 1          ; return 1 in ECX if an extended key is pressed
quit:
    ret
```